# Pax Exam: Resolve Karaf feature repository (XML file) from non-standard Maven repository

Tags: java, maven, apache-karaf, pax-exam

I am using Pax Exam and am trying to resolve a feature repository and the contained features via a nonstandard maven repository.

`CoreOptions.repository()` (followed by `CoreOptions.cleanCaches()` seems not to have any influence on the behaviour of Karaf itself. The `etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg` only lists maven central, which is indeed the only repository that is search for my `KarafDistributionOption.feature()`. (As evidenced by the Karaf log)
I am able to specify a direct `http://`-Url to the feature repository which gets resolved successfully. Then however the resolution of all bundles referenced from this repository fails, as they are part of the same repository.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this in your Pax Exam configuration for adding any additional Maven Repository:

```
KarafDistributionOption.
    editConfigurationFilePut("etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg", 
    "org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories", "http://<YOUR-INTERNAL-MAVENREPO>");
```